# Which would be better for storing account data local storage or cookies?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to store account data but I don't know whether I should use local storage or cookies.

Originally I used local storage but when you logged out you'd have to make a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies and localStorage are front end only and should not be used for accounts. You should use a backend system for storing user data.

You can set up an API (with Express (Node), PHP, etc.) that connects to a database (e.g. MariaDB).